# php - how to get accurate server time

Tags: javascript, php, time, server

i am running on my Ubuntu server every 30 minutes one script via crontab.
The content of this script is not important, but i want to notify my server users about accurate time , when the script will be triggered (i have webpage something like lottery with drawing every 30 minutes)

I tried the following:
PHP

```
$min = date('i');
$sec = date('s');
if (($min>=30)&&($sec==0)) {
$tt=((60-($min))*60)+$sec;  
}
if (($min>=30)&&($sec>0)) {
$tt=((60-($min+1))*60)+$sec;    
}
if (($min<30)&&($sec>0)) {
$tt=((30-($min+1))*60)+$sec;    
}
if (($min<30)&&($sec==0)) {
$tt=((30-($min)*60))+$sec;  
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
var seconds = <?php echo $tt;?>;
function secondPassed() {
    var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
    var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);

    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
</script>
```

HTML:

..

```
<span id="countdown" class="timer"></span>
```

..

the problem is, when i am refreshing the page with F5, it shows very different times (+/- 10-20 seconds, or more difference)

any idea how to fix that? How to get very precise time data from the server?
i googled around, but i was unable to find solution for this problem.

thanks for advices

Comment: The network is not instantaneous.  That is impossible.

Comment: There might also be some caching involved. The generation for `$tt` looks fine

Comment: `setInterval` is not precise.  Check how much time has actually passed using the browser's API.

Comment: @SLaks - i dont think the problem is setInterval -  time difference between two refreshes within one second shows 10-15 seconds difference, sometimes up,sometimes down..  it looks like the value that i am calculating in php showing wrong results (maybe not accurate date() function? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved, it IS possible..
on the main post i have some bug in PHP part..
my working php to solve $tt (time left until next half hour interval)

PHP

```
unset($tt);unset($min);unset($sec);
$min = date('i');
$sec = date('s');

$tt=3600-($min*60+$sec);
if ($tt>=1800) {$tt=$tt-1800;}
```